# Difference between "on my way to be 25" and "on my way to being 25"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Set 1:

> 1. China is close **to be** the centre of world trade.

> 2. China is close **to being** the centre of world trade.

Set 2:

> 1. I am on my way **to be** 25.

> 2. I am on my way **to being** 25

Which is the correct form, the first or the second? What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Answer (score 0):

How to tell:

China is close to **being** the centre of world trade.

Can also be stated as:
**Being** the centre of world trade is what China is close to.

**Being** rich is not easy to achieve.

So, being is a gerund-noun and gerund-nouns can be subjects of a sentence. The verb be cannot. Be rich to achieve. [buzzer]

Introduction to gerunds:

["gerunds by me"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168811/are-there-tenseless-sentences-in-english/168828#168828)

Answer (score -1):

The World Trade Center is, famously, the complex of buildings destroyed in the 9/11 attacks and now rebuilt. However, you could say *China is close to becoming the centre/center of world trade.*

We would not use the infinitive in sentences like this.

Comment: thankyou :) So you mean even in the set2 both forms are wrong??

Answer (score -1):

*Close to* and *(the) way to* both take *-ing* clauses, not infinitive clause.

There is no logic or general rule to this, and it has no discernable relationship to the meaning: it is just a property of those particular words. It is no more predictable than the fact that the adjective *close* cannot mean "which has been closed", whereas the adjective *open* can mean "which has been opened".

For examples of similar words that go the other way, consider *ready to* and *prepared to*, both of which require an infinitive clause, not an *-ing* clause.

Comment: "On my way" can take the infinitive: "I'm on my way to buy dinner", "I'm on my way to get my hair cut", etc. "Close" however does not.

Comment: That's a different meaning of _way_: a literal journey to a specified purpose, as opposed to a metaphorical journey where something is seen as an end-goal (not necessarily a purpose).

Comment: Also, far from being x.